# Get maven dependency from child POM

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Is there a way, without modifying parent POM to use version of some dependency from child POM?

For example in parent POM i have:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
<artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
<version>2.4.8</version>
</dependency>
```

In child POM:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
<artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
<version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: In my opinion its not possible.

Comment: Where do you want to use the version from the child?

Comment: In my module(project) I want to use child version. Because parent POM is for the whole company I cannot modify it.

Comment: The problem is, after adding parent tag, my project won't build anymore, because it using parent version for dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you put that dependency in the `dependencyManagement` section of your child pom, then modules from your child pom **downwards** (it will not affect siblings of your child pom) will use the version you specify. It will, effectively, override the version in the parent pom.

Comment: I have tried it. Won't build project. Stacktrace says about every package that it doesn't exist:
DbUnitDatabaseConnectionFactory.java:[3,27] package org.dbunit.database does not exist

Comment: You need the dependency in the `dependencies` section as well.

Comment: Sure, I have all that.